# why can I delete a root owned file through samba share that is an NFS mounted folder?

Tags: permissions, samba, nfs, samba4, nfsv4

- RHEL 7.9
- a server having the physical mount of `/data` has SELINUX as enforcing with the selinx bool `samba_share_nfs` set to `on`; this `/data` folder is NFS exported
- a few NFS client servers mount this `/data` folder with `no_root_squash` and as `NFS vers=4.1`
- one NFS client as `root` writes `/data/log.txt` and this file has permissions `-rw-r--r--.    1 root    root`
- each NFS client server also samba shares out it's NFS mounted `/data` folder, where the `/data/` folder permissions are `drwxrwx---. 1 ron    users`; see below for `smb.conf`
- through samba from my win10 pc, logged in as `ron` I can go to `\\server\data` and delete `log.txt` even though it has `root.root rw-r-r` permissions.  **Why?**

  - *my code that writes `log.txt` has to be run as `root`, and I am ok with anyone being able to read my `log.txt` (I actually want that) I just don't want `log.txt` to be able to be deleted or edited.*

---

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf

[global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    disable spoolss = yes

[data]
    comment = data
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
    path = /data
    directory mask = 770
    create mask = 660
```

Comment: If you own `\\server\data` then you can delete files in the directory no matter who owns them. You are essentially editing the directory, not the file, so your directory permissions win.

Comment: does the `owner of a directory` have full delete capability of anything within ?  Even if some files/folders are not owned by the directory owne r?  This has nothing to do with NFS nor Samba ?  It seems what I am observing (as described above) violates fundamental permissions logic.

Comment: Yes, the owner of the directory has full control over the contents of the directory. This seems to be consistent with permissions logic. If you own a file, you can control the content of the file. If I own a directory, I control the content of the directory. It's been this way in UNIX file systems since the first file system was designed.

Comment: I was not aware as a user I could delete a file that was `-rw-r-r` owned by `root.root` even if it was under my home directory.  I can, it will prompt with *remove write-protected regular file*.  A delete stipulation I wasn't obviously aware of.  Thanks